# Turn GWT Asyncronous call (DispatchAsync) into Syncronous

Tags: gwt, asynchronous, authentication, synchronous, gwtp

Function `canReveal()` returns true if class `ClientState` has user information. If not, it first tries to get that user information using asyncronous call to `GetUser`. What I need to do inside the `IF` is to wait somehow until this asyncronous call returns (`onSuccess`), so that I can check whether `ClientState` has now the user information or not. How can I do that? Thanks

```
public class MyGatekeeper implements Gatekeeper{

private DispatchAsync dispatcher;

@Inject
public MyGatekeeper(DispatchAsync dispatcher) {
        this.dispatcher = dispatcher;
}

@Override
public boolean canReveal() {
    if(ClientState.isUserLoggedin()==false) {
        dispatcher.execute(new GetUser(Window.Location.getHref()),
        new DispatchCallback<GetUserResult>() {
                @Override
                        public void onSuccess(GetUserResult result) {
                if (!result.getErrorText().isEmpty()) {
                     Window.alert(result.getErrorText());
                     return;
                }
                ClientState.setUserInfo(result.getUserInfo());
            }
        });
        return ClientState.isUserLoggedin(); // WAIT till onSuccess returns!
    }
}
    return ClientState.isUserLoggedin();
}
```

Comment: Careful on trying to make sync calls from typically async XHR's. Synchronous XHR is slated to be deprecated in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to have `canReveal` take a `Callback<Boolean>`:

```
public void canReveal(Callback<Boolean> cb) {
  if (!ClientState.isUserLoggedIn()) {
    dispatcher.execute(..., new DispatchCallback<Result>() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(Result result) {
        cb.onSuccess(result.isGoodOrWhatever());
      }
    });
  } else {
    cb.onSuccess(true); // User is logged in
  }
}
```

Unfortunately there's no way to tell GWT to "wait" for the async callback, since that would basically freeze JS execution, since JS is single-threaded.

Comment: Thank you! But this way I cannot return a boolean, right? Function has to be always null?

Comment: It *can* return whatever you want, but it won't be able to return whether or not the callback was successful or not, since that's not known at the time the function returns, only after the callback is finished.

Comment: Thanks! So returning to my original question, could we say that it is not possible to return a boolean once the DispatchAsync callback has finished, right?

Comment: If you call `return false` from within the callback, it will be a compilation error (since the method is `void`) -- either way, that isn't what you want. So yes, you can't "return" from within the callback.